# Setting text color to theme in Android is not working

Tags: android, android-theme, android-styles

I am developing an Android app using Android Studio. Frankly, I am not good at Android Development. I am having a problem with setting theme to my app. I am setting text color for the whole application in the style resource file as a  theme. But it is not working.

This is my color resource file:

[image]

As you can see, I set both text colors to red.

This is my theme in style resource file:

[image]

I set the theme for the application in manifest file like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.deltatripagent.deltatripagent" >

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

But when I run text color is not changing. You can see below.

[image]

How can I set text color for the whole application?

Answer (score 0):

Your activity theme is correctly set as `AppTheme.NoActionBar`. However, that theme doesn't have a parent within your styles.xml, which means the TextView color won't be changed from the default. You can fix this by inheriting from AppTheme like thus:

```
<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar" parent="AppTheme">
```